# Partial Derivatives (why do they behave commutatively here)?

Tags: partial-derivative

I encountered this in a derivation of the 1D wave equation.

Why does the order of application not matter?

$$ expr = f(x,t)$$

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \left(  \frac{\partial  }{\partial x }  \left(expr \right ) \right)  = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(  \frac{\partial  }{\partial t } \left(expr \right )  \right) $$

> why is this true?

(*Is it also true for Total Derivatives in the same situation?*)

Comment: What is with the $expr$?

Comment: Equality of Mixed Partials is guaranteed when the first partials are continuously differentiable.  But that is not a necessary condition.

Comment: nothing I just wanted to spread out the parentheses :)

Comment: No, I meant why write $expr=f(x,t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Schwarz's/Clairaut's/Young's Theorem $$f_{xt}(x,t)=f_{tx}(x,t)$$ or in your notation

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t\partial x}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial t}$$

if $f$ is twice continuously differentiable. (A weaker sufficient condition for symmetry of second-order partial derivatives is that all first-order partial derivatives are differentiable.)

About your question regarding "total derivatives" if you mean the partial derivatives of a composition of functions then yes, if the composition is twice continuously differentiable.

Comment: Nice! I now know when I can use this (when my function is twice differentiable...).